# POST method returning 404 even though GET method returns 302

Tags: javascript, http, post, http-status-code-404, fetch-api

**The problem**

**I have this fake API:**

```
[{"task_id":"44","task_title":"task1"},{"task_id":"45","task_title":"task2"},{"task_id":"46","task_title":"task1"},{"task_id":"47","task_title":"task2"}]
```

**When I try to access it using a fetch GET method, using the code below:**

```
function getData(){
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/tasks')
    .then(res => res.json())   
    .then((data) => {console.log(data)});}
getData();
```

**I get the expected result in the console.**

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {task_id: '44', task_title: 'task1'}
1: {task_id: '45', task_title: 'task2'}
2: {task_id: '46', task_title: 'task1'}
3: {task_id: '47', task_title: 'task2'}
```

**Yet, when I try to access it through a POST method, like so:**

```
function postData(){
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/tasks',{
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            task_title: 'testTask'
        })    
    })
    .then(res =>{
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log('ERROR'))
}
```

**I get this unexpected 404:**

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/tasks 404 (Not Found)
```

**My API is set as so using Node.js and express:**

```
app.get('/api/tasks', (req, res)=>{
  db.SelectAll().then(data => {res.json(data)});
})
```

**db is just:**

```
const db = require('./db/db.js');
```

**and SelectAll() is:**

```
async function SelectAll() {
try {
    const res = await client.query("SELECT * FROM tasks");
    return res.rows;
    } catch(err){
    console.log(err);   
    }
client.end();
};
```

**What is causing this 404?**

Comment: You only have an enpoint for GET, not for POST. Did you mean to call with GET or do you want the endpoint to (also?) respond to POST?

Comment: I meant to have a POST request, I just hadn't realized that my api would be the one responsible to set the POST endpoint.

If I set a POST endpoint, can I also use GET methods on it? Or should I create both POST and GET endpoints to handle both methods?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> app.get('/api/tasks', (req, res)=>{
>   db.SelectAll().then(data => {res.json(data)});
> })
> ```

Your code registers a GET handler. You have not used `app.post` to register a POST handler.

While this **should** mean that a POST request to that path gets a `405 Method Not Allowed` response, [Express does not support this automatically](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2414) and gives a `404 Not Found` instead.

If you want to do something when a POST request is made to that path, then you need to use `app.post` to register a function that will run and do whatever it is that you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! I just started to learn about API's, and thought that the fetch request using the post method would suffice. Thanks again for the clear answer.